# how to pass php value as parameter in anchor tag href

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to pass php value as parameter in anchor hreh.Here i have the problem while fetching the 'c_id'.c_id is the primary key.
  Here I attached my html code and php code

```
<?php
          include "config.php";
          $sql="select c_name from client order by c_name asc limit 10";
          $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
          echo "<table border='1' align=center width=500 style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
           echo "<tr height =10><td width=300 align=center><b>Client name</b></td><td colspan=2 align=center><b>Action</b></td></tr>";
          while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
          {
           $id=$fet['c_id'];
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td align=center width=100>".$fet["c_name"]."</td>";
           echo "<td align=center width=100><a href='client_details.php?id=".echo $id."'>Edit</a></td><td><a href=''>Delete</a></td>";
           echo "</tr>";  
           echo "</table><br>";
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Why `.echo $id.`? You're using it correctly in the line before, without `echo`. Why add `echo` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
echo "<td align=center width=100><a href='client_details.php?id=".echo $id."'>Edit</a></td><td><a href=''>Delete</a></td>";
```

To:

```
echo "<td align=center width=100><a href='client_details.php?id=".$id."'>Edit</a></td><td><a href=''>Delete</a></td>";
```

Because you already used the `echo`. You can't use `echo` inside another `echo`.

Comment: i cant fetch the value using  $id=$fet['c_id'];

Comment: Are you sure you query return some results? Check if you query fails by using`mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. BTW. using `mysql_*` is not very good anymore because it's deprecated. Use PDO or `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_`

Comment: $sql="select c_name from client order by c_name asc limit 10"; is not working

Comment: Then that's the reason why it isn't displaying. What does PHPMyAdmin shows when you paste the query?

Comment: this query is ececutes in phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you setup a database connection? What is in your `config.php`?

Comment: $sql="select * from client order by c_name asc limit 10"; thank you..now it ill get executed

Comment: No, you need to setup the database connection. I do not recommend `mysql_*` but use `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` to setup a connection. If you are new in this then start with learning `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of learning the deprecated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope It works for you

```
 <a href="your app url.php?data=phpvariable">Read more</a>
```

Comment: <a href="your app url.php?data=<?=$string?>">Read more</a> 
stackoverflow ancker tag read as data so try this one

Comment: hi, Welcome :) Please ensure to use `Code` tags when posting code, also please ensure to add an explanation of your answer for better understanding. Simply posting code without any explanation is not recommended.